# mysql-connector-python in flask app on docker not connected

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, flask-restful

**There is no problem in my localhost and good run in my pc
but in docker not running and this error**

**connected**

```
def get_database_connection():
    """connects to the MySQL database and returns the connection"""
    return mysql.connector.connect(
        host=config.MYSQL_HOST,
        user=config.MYSQL_USERNAME,
        passwd=config.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        db = config.MYSQL_DB_NAME,
        port=config.MYSQL_PORT,
        charset='utf8'
    )
```

**config.py**

```
MYSQL_HOST = "localhost"
MYSQL_USERNAME = "root" 
MYSQL_PASSWORD = ""
MYSQL_PORT = 3306
MYSQL_DB_NAME = "newsdb"
```

**---------- Error --------**

```
** Operational MODE: preforking ***
build Tables
error --- > 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x55e5696d31a0 pid: 10 (default app)
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
```

**Project Structure**

```
app
├── admin
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── config.py
├── db.py
├── error_handlers.py
├── __init__.py
├── robots
│   ├── robot_runner.py
│   └── robots.py
├── routes.py
├── schema.sql
├── static
│   
├── templates
└── test
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.8


COPY . /app

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /var/www/requirements.txt

RUN apt update && apt install -qy libmariadbclient-dev gcc

RUN pip3 install -r /var/www/requirements.txt
```

this project run on my localhost and not problem ... just want run image docker show error and not connect to mysql ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Dockerfile` does not include a MySQL server with the image. Best practices for containers are to keep one service in each container, so running a MySQL service containerized would imply running two separate containers -- one for your web application and one for your MySQL server.

[docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a reasonable way to handle this use case. Specify a `docker-compose.yml` containing your service definitions:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports: [ "5000:5000" ]
    links: [ "mysql" ]
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    [... some other configuration parameters to set up the database root account ...]
    volumes: [ "mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql" ]
volumes: { mysqldata: {} }
```

The MySQL image referenced here is the [official MySQL image on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

After this, you can connect to "mysql" instead of "localhost" in your application's config file.

Alternatively, point your application config file to an already running MySQL service with your database set up. Remember that `localhost` in the container is not your local machine -- it's the container. You may need to [appropriately configure Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/) for the container to access your machine or the MySQL host.